# How to run a macOS app as root and use system calls?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode9.2

I'm trying to run the `setpriority` command from my macOS app (objective-c). It never works and I'm assuming it is because the app is not being run as the root user.

- I'm logged in to the admin account on my computer
- I've tried opening the app with `sudo`
- I've tried using `chmod` on the app
- I've tried adding the app to the `Accessibility` list under `Security and Privacy`

Xcode version 9.2 (9C40b)

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run as `root`, or you want to run with `sudo`? There's a difference. Running as root is definitely not recommended, you will get strange behaviour from the system.

You wrote:

> I've tried opening the app with sudo

That should work. How have you tried? You need to call the binary within the .app bundle. Running `open` against the bundle won't work.

e.g.

```
sudo ./Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

Comment: This returned `Illegal instruction: 4`. I'm not sure what I could have done wrong, I've been having a hard time looking for a solution for this error

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? Remove any entitlements in Xcode and try again.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to run GUI apps on macOS as root. Instead, you should factor out the part of your application which needs root access into a separate helper tool, launch that tool as root using the `SMJobBless()` function, and then communicate with the tool using XPC.

Apple provides the [EvenBetterAuthorizationSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html) example code to give a pretty good basic framework to work from.

EDIT: I decided to make my own authorization sample project a while ago that should be a little easier to use than the venerable `EvenBetterAuthorizationSample`. You can check it out at [CSAuthSample](https://github.com/CharlesJS/CSAuthSample).

Comment: Even with it not being recommended, I still want to explore at my own risk. Is it even possible to the app as root?

Comment: @Quack In the early years of OS X, it was possible, although not a good idea. Nowadays I think that if you try it, the app will fail to connect to the window server. It's for the best; there were some pretty nasty privilege-escalation exploits that used that mechanism back in the day.

Comment: I guess that makes sense and is for the better. I'd love to read more about that for myself (now I'm curious). Would you happen to know any articles/papers about modifying priority and security?

Comment: @Quack The EvenBetterAuthorizationSample code is a great resource for this. It's not documented as well as I'd like, but if you read through the code and the comments, it's possible to figure out what it's doing. I've been meaning to clean up the code for my own home-brewed Swift equivalent, which has a slightly nicer interface, so I can put it up online, but I never seem to get around to it. :-/